# Knockout observable variable undefined

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a viewModel, there is an observable variable but when I assign the value to the observable it will become undefined.

```
var ScDmfViewModel = (function () {
  var selectedRequestItem = ko.observable("");
  return {
    SelectedItemUom: selectedItemUom,
  };
})();
```

In another Javascript File I assign the Value 1 to it:

```
ScDmfViewModel.SelectedItemUom(1);
```

But As soon as I debug this its value shows

```
ScDmfViewModel.SelectedItemUom():undefined
```

Comment: Might be just a typo, but `selectedRequestItem` != `selectedItemUom`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is before i defined the Code I am calling a JSON Call where it will return the Value and Reset the Observable Value. Thats Why Undeifiend

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you wanted:

```
var ScDmfViewModel = (function () {
  var selectedRequestItem = ko.observable("");
return {
SelectedItemUom: selectedRequestItem
};
})();
```

Comment: Why -1? original code has an error, and this fixes it.

Comment: You should probably add some detail to your answer regarding what's wrong with the original code and how this fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.
Define a constructor to your ViewModel with the parameter selectedRequestItem 
and accessor get set for modify your parameter. Like object class.

```
// *** definition viewModel ***
function ScDmfViewModel() {

    this.selectedRequestItem  = ko.observable();

    this.setSelectedItemUom = function (value) {
         this.selectedRequestItem(value);
    };

    this.getSelectedItemUom = function() {
        return this.selectedRequestItem();
    };
}

// ** Create vm ** //
var vm = new ScDmfViewModel();

// set data
vm.setSelectedItemUom(1);

// get data
alert(vm.getSelectedItemUom());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/LkqTU/